# ath9k driver suddenly doesn't see channel 13 anymore

Tags: wireless, atheros

Suddenly, after upgrade to Linux kernel 3.11.0-19, my wireless card with the ath9k driver is no longer seeing the 13th channel, even though it worked fine for the last year and half. It also still works fine on another Ubuntu laptop and an Android phone.

How can I re-enable the 13th channel? It is very necessary as most of the channels are taken here.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the `wireless-crda` and the `iw` packages which automatically seem to have fixed things, before I saw these replies. Thank you for the answers, however!

Comment: dude, **why isn't this installed by default**???

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be having the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04, switching from Kernel 5.4.x to 5.13.x. Installing `wireless-crda` did not help at all.
On an Arch Linux forum I found the remark that crda is actually deprecated over `wireless-regdb`.

Anyway. What solved it for me, was to force the `regdomain` when loading the `cfg80211` module:

Add a file `/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf` with the content

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=DE # or your country's 2-char ISO code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your regulatory domain

Edit your `/etc/default/crda` and set your country code.

There is more info by running `dmesg`.

See. [regulatory domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147066/how-can-i-change-an-atheros-wireless-nic-region-regulatory-domain-in-ubuntu)

Comment: While this is true, if you run dmesg you should see that it still initializes as 00 *before* *changing* to whatever regdom sets. So, if you are expecting a frequency outside channels 1-11 you are basically out of luck these days. Oh, you can *change* to the correct domaing but you will keep getting kicked off the channel every time it initializes