# Frequent deauthentication from Wifi (Reason: 6) in a Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

For a few days now, my wifi is getting disrupted every few minutes. I use a 'vanilla' Ubuntu installation (i.e Unity, NetworkManager etc.). After an hour or so, the connection gets severed completely and NetworkManager can't find the network anymore. Toggling "Enable Wi-Fi" in the NetworkManager-menu allows me to find and connect to the network again.

This is an excerpt from /var/log/syslog:

```
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.006043] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (Reason: 6)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 reason=6
May 14 16:50:51 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason 6)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270' freq=2447 MHz)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.034507] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.035050] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042178] wlan0: send auth to 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (try 1/3)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
May 14 16:50:51 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270' freq=2447 MHz)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042526] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042533] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042539] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042543] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042547] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042550] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.042554] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.044622] wlan0: authenticated
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.046291] wlan0: associate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (try 1/3)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.056055] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
May 14 16:50:51 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: Associated with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6
May 14 16:50:51 terminus kernel: [ 4208.065893] wlan0: associated
May 14 16:50:51 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
May 14 16:50:51 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May 14 16:50:51 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 14 16:50:51 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
May 14 16:51:55 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.188238] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (Reason: 6)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 reason=6
May 14 16:52:27 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason 6)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270' freq=2447 MHz)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.215024] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.215540] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6
May 14 16:52:27 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
May 14 16:52:27 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270' freq=2447 MHz)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.219680] wlan0: send auth to 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (try 1/3)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.222003] wlan0: authenticated
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.222790] wlan0: associate with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (try 1/3)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223063] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223072] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223078] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223083] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223087] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223090] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.223094] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.226833] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
May 14 16:52:27 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 14 16:52:27 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: Associated with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6
May 14 16:52:27 terminus kernel: [ 4304.232953] wlan0: associated
May 14 16:52:27 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
May 14 16:52:27 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May 14 16:52:27 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 14 16:52:27 terminus NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
May 14 16:53:55 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May 14 16:54:00 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May 14 16:54:05 terminus wpa_supplicant[907]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:24:fe:a3:98:f6 [GTK=TKIP]
```

Other relevant information:

```
root@terminus:~# lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 88:53:2e:42:0b:71
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.3.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:52 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff

root@terminus:~# lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
btrfs                 835954  0 
raid6_pq               97812  1 btrfs
xor                    21411  1 btrfs
ufs                    74890  0 
qnx4                   13317  0 
hfsplus               107516  0 
hfs                    54677  0 
minix                  36140  0 
ntfs                   97369  0 
msdos                  17332  0 
jfs                   181348  0 
xfs                   912173  0 
libcrc32c              12644  2 xfs,btrfs
ctr                    13049  1 
ccm                    17773  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
joydev                 17381  0 
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143060  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55624  2 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
psmouse               102222  0 
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
serio_raw              13462  0 
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
rfcomm                 69160  8 
arc4                   12608  2 
bnep                   19624  2 
snd_hda_intel          52355  3 
iwldvm                232285  0 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
mac80211              626489  1 iwldvm
nouveau              1097199  1 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
btusb                  32412  0 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             395423  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
i915                  783485  3 
dell_wmi               12761  0 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
ttm                    85115  1 nouveau
snd                    69238  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
drm_kms_helper         52758  2 i915,nouveau
wmi                    19177  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
drm                   302817  7 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 i915,nouveau
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82274  1 mei_me
mac_hid                13205  0 
video                  19476  2 i915,nouveau
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52616  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            62209  0 
ahci                   25819  1 
r8169                  67581  0 
libahci                32168  1 ahci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
```

I guess it could be a hardware-related issue, but as far as I know, the problem does not occur on Windows (8, 64bit). However, since the reconnect is so fast, I might have missed it so far.

Any idea what the issue could be? What is "Reason 6" and what can cause it? How can I debug the problem further?

It seems like [Network Issues since Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454427/network-issues-since-trusty) could be the same issue. I would appreciate if someone could post my link there, since I don't have enough reputation to do so.

I disabled mode-N wireless by adding 'options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1' to some file in /etc/modprobe.d/. I had no disconnects since then!

Answer (score 9):

I have had similar issues, and found the following helped (not solved) my problem:

Check which regulatory agency your wireless is set to use:

```
iw reg get
```

Mine defaulted to '00', which is unset.  As I'm in the US, I then ran

```
sudo iw reg set US
```

This setting for my wireless seems to have made the behaviour of my device much more consistent, although I am also running

in the file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf to disable the 802.11n protocol

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

and in the file /etc/sysctl.conf I am disabling the ipv6 protocols

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and finally, my wireless router has been set not to use QOS/WWN

Comment: Thank you! Fixing the country code (as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/171398/109710)) lead to a strikingly decreased pause until a wifi connection is established!

Comment: I can verify that setting the regulatory agency from 00 to US worked for me.  My wifi connection used to lag or drop all together when I was logging in and I would get a Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT error in dmesg.  This solution fixed it.

Comment: how can I make this setting "sticky" so that I don't have to reset it after every reboot?

Comment: The file in modprobe and the /etc/sysctl.conf file would be 'sticky' - the regulatory agency is best fixed done by amending  `/etc/default/crda` and making the last line: `REGDOMAIN=US`

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to change auto channel to fix channel on my wlan router.

I also got error messages like `wlan0: deauthenticated from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` all the time and I found out (with command `wpa_cli`) that this happens after the wlan router changes its channel. Therefore I use a fixed wlan channel now which solves this issue.

You can see the currently used channel using `wpa_cli`. It shows you when the channel is being changed. When the wlan channel is changing you can see that the frequency is different from before.

It's not about to find any free wlan channels but when the channel is being changed, it seems that there is an issue with wpa_supplicant and it doesn't work any more but instead it is trying to reconnect all the time without success. After that time you get a lot of `wlan0: deauthenticated from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` messages (mac address will be different). Therefore the solution is to use fix the wlan channel to whatever channel you like.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you elaborate on what Ubuntu commands you used to find the unused channel?  (Your answer has nothing to do with Ubuntu, so unless you elaborate, it might be deleted automatically by the system)

Comment: Don't post additional comments but [edit] your answer and add the Ubuntu commands you used to find the free channel...  ;-)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear...  I'm trying to help you to [write a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer), so [edit] your answer and make it better before it gets deleted because of "low quality"... :-(  Comments are for discussion or to request additional info and are not part of the answer.

Comment: Hi Faby, you are right. I updated my answer.

Comment: :-)  Good one now!  Upvoted!  (though I would take a channel not in use by any of your neighbours...  **;-)**