# Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] disconnect every 10 minutes

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I recently installed **Ubuntu 14.04** in my laptop machine. I use wifi to connect to the network. Everything works fine except that I am not able to access network after 15 minutes or so.

I have to do `ifdown wlan0` followed by `ifup wlan0` to bring back the internet connection.

I got this solution which suggested to reinstall some modules from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220377) but unfortunately it did not help fix my problem.

```
sudo rmmod iwldvm #otherwise iwlwifi refuses to stop
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
sudo modprobe iwldvm
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks as below.

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.9
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid My_SSID
wpa-psk My_SSID_Password
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
dns-search lan
dns-domain lan
```

Is there something that am missing? It is frustrating to just run `ifdown` and `ifup` every 10 minutes. I could have a script to run every 10 minutes to run `ping`, `ifdown` and `ifup` or so but that seems a somewhat ugly solution. I removed my connection details from network manager but the problem still persists.

```
lspci -d $(lspci -nn | grep 0280 | grep -oP '\[\K[^]]*:[^]]*') -k
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Output of `inxi` command is,

```
CPU~Dual core Intel Core i5-2410M CPU (-HT-MCP-) clocked at Min:800.000Mhz Max:2301.000Mhz Kernel~3.13.0-36-generic x86_64 Up~7:16 Mem~2110.7/3860.2MB HDD~500.1GB(4.0% used) Procs~211 Client~Shell inxi~1.9.17
```

**EDIT 2**

I just got disconnected from wifi and when I did `dmesg | tail -50`, I saw this piece of information which I thought might be useful.

```
[26306.892459] wlan0: deauthenticated from f8:e4:fb:99:cb:99 (Reason: 6)
```

I tried the option as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/471492/334241) and added an entry `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file to disable the 802.11 protocol. However, I still faced connectivity issue after a while. I see this information while I was disconnected.

```
cat /var/log/syslog | tail -10
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f8:e4:fb:99:cb:99 (SSID='my_ssid' freq=2437 MHz)
```

**EDIT 3**

Since I have configured the network using `/etc/network/interfaces`, I completely removed the network manager using `sudo apt-get purge network-manager`. However, this option also did not help me. I am looking for some other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the below changes in my `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file and a system restart, I do not see any frequent disconnects.

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 wd_disable=1`

I believe it might help someone in future.

**References**

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1899352